# Margin/Padding in percentage in XML

Tags: android, layout

I am new in android development. I want to set margin & padding in Xml,not in dp or px but in percentage. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hey i think this is not possible 
[Look Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996571/android-how-do-i-set-a-percentage-padding-margin-so-edittext-has-10-margin-on-e)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is not possible, though You better do it by taking width and height of screen like below in your java code, and

```
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
 int width = display.getWidth();
 int height = display.getHeight();
```

then calculate your margin from screen size, and set it by

```
  setmargin(int x) //method of view/layout.
```

this way you can set margin depending on the screen size not fixed for all screen, and basically it is like setting in percentage but from Java code.

Comment: Using getWidth() and getHeight() is deprecated in API level 13+. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html. 

Use getSize(point) instead.

Comment: @maraci check my another answer for your concern Link >> http://stackoverflow.com/a/11483404/519718

Answer (score 1):

It became possible with [Guidelines](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7) introduced in ConstraintLayout.

Here's the example of TextView placed at 60% of screen width and 25% of screen height:

[image: Layout Editor]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to share sreen width between your controls in percentage. Best way to do that in android is using `weight` property for them. Check following URL for more details.

[Android Layout Paramas guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)

regards,
Aqif Hamid

Answer (score 0):

Though it is quite late, it can be done with Android percentageRelativeLayout 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html
One can use percentage with some attributes but not all are supported. Like padding is still not supported in percentage whereas margin is.