# How do android screen coordinates work?

Tags: android, android-animation, coordinate-systems

I am working with Android `Animation` and I have found the Android coordinate system to be quite confusing so I am here to ask this question about how coordinates work in Android. I am following this image for moving one view to another but it seems it's not working:

[image]

Comment: in fact, what you've drawn is actually correct, just rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise.

Answer (score 335, accepted):

[image]

**This image presents both orientation(Landscape/Portrait)**

To get MaxX and MaxY, read on.

For Android device screen coordinates,  below concept will work.

```
Display mdisp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point mdispSize = new Point();
mdisp.getSize(mdispSize);
int maxX = mdispSize.x; 
int maxY = mdispSize.y;
```

**EDIT:- ** **for devices supporting android api level older than 13. Can use below code.**

```
    Display mdisp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int maxX= mdisp.getWidth();
    int maxY= mdisp.getHeight();
```

(x,y) :-

1) **(0,0)** is top left corner.

2)  **(maxX,0)** is top right corner

3) **(0,maxY)** is bottom left corner

4) **(maxX,maxY)** is bottom right corner

here maxX and maxY are screen maximum height and width in pixels, which we have retrieved in above given code.

Comment: If we've got the `View` with `layout_width="1" layout_height="1"` would it mean that top left is (0,0) and bottom right is (1, 1)? Wouldn't that mean that `View`'s width = 2 and height = 2? Contradiction.

Comment: @AAnkit can you please confrim , this is valid for both screen orientations (Portrait and Landscape), does screen orientation change affects on (0,0) -> top left corner.
(maxX,0) -> top right corner
(0,maxY) -> bottom left corner
(maxX,maxY) -> bottom right corner

Answer (score 20):

For Android API level 13 and  you need to use this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int maxX = size.x; 
int maxY = size.y;
```

Then (0,0) is top left corner and (maxX,maxY) is bottom right corner of the screen.

The 'getWidth()' for screen size is deprecated since API 13

Furthermore [getwidth()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getWidth()) and [getHeight()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getHeight()) are methods of [android.view.View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View)
 class in android.So when your java class extends View class there is no windowManager overheads.

```
          int maxX=getwidht();
          int maxY=getHeight();
```

as simple as that.

Answer (score 9):

This picture will remove everyone's confusion hopefully which is collected from [there](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/06/15-useful-robotium-code-snippets-for-android-test-automation.html).

[image: Android screen coordinate]