# Get right coordinates on touchdown on android device

Tags: android, libgdx, coordinates, projection, orthographic

I'm programming a button in LIBGX. It works good on desktop, but when I launch it on android, I have to touch in a different place to trigger it (Im using a real Android device, not an AVD) Here's a pic describing it:

[image]

Below the TouchDown code:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter () {
       public boolean touchDown (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
          // your touch down code here
         Vector3 coords = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
         camara.unproject(coords);

          if(coords.x >= 52 && coords.x<=129 && coords.y >= 158  && coords.y<=253){
              shoot(1);
          }
          return true; // return true to indicate the event was handled
       }
    });
```

I had the same problem without Vector3, I started using it because it was adviced, but didn't solve much. Here's the declaration of the camera:

```
camara = new OrthographicCamera();
camara.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
```

I have done some research, but can't find the right solution, and I find the cameras (ortographic, real world, etc) very confusing. I will keep digging, this has taken hours and had to make the question. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Not sure if I can help you directly, but I can tell you, that x and y coordinates on Android is somewhat inverted compared to a computer. The x and y coordinates starts in the upper left corner and not the lower left corner as on other operating systems. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483345/how-android-screen-coordinates-works for a bit more explanation (sorry couldn't find anything directly from the documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the origin `(0,0)` in Android screen is situated at **top-left** corner of the screen. Thus, when you add values to `y axis` the object go towards bottom and when subtract values the object goes upwards.

**In Android devices:**

```
 Origin
 |
 V
 *-------------------------------
 | ----> X axis                  |
 | |                             |
 | |                             |
 | V Y-axis                      |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
  -------------------------------
```

**In desktops:**

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 |                                                             |
 | ^ Y axis                                                    |
 | |                                                           |
 | |                                                           |
 | ----> X axis                                                |
 *-------------------------------------------------------------
 ^
 | 
 Origin
```

**Possible History:**

As screen space calculations started when television sets were used as screens. The raster gun of a TV is also starting at the **top left** corner, so this was accepted as the origin.

For further reference you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483345/how-do-android-screen-coordinates-work)