# Moving imageView from one position to another

Tags: android, animation, imageview, position

I am making a game in which an `imageView` of a ball need to move from one point on the screen to another one. The starting point of the ball is on an `imageView` of a hole and I want it to end on another `imageView` of a hole.

Anyway, I didn't find any way to get the position of the starting point (the first hole) or the end point (the second hole). I tried to use     `getLocationOnScreen(Loc)` but it returns 0 all the time.

I really need your help because I am looking for a solution for a long time.
If someone can write a detailed answer that would work I will be grateful.
Thanks in advance :)

Here is what I tried:

```
int fromLoc[] = new int[2];
holes[6].getLocationOnScreen(fromLoc);     
float startX = fromLoc[0];
float startY = fromLoc[1];
```

and this:

```
RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams params = 
    (RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams) imgBall0.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(holes[5].getLeft(), holes[5].getTop(), 
    holes[5].getRight(), holes[5].getBottom()); //all in pixels
imgBall0.setLayoutParams(params);
```

`holes[5]` is the ending point to which the `imgBall0` needs to arrive.
`holes[5]` is an `imageButton` which is in a `relativeLayout` and in a `LinearLayout`.

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you show some of the code you tried?

Comment: Maybe you can try [this][1]. If want to move the view to follow your finger.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398057/android-move-a-view-on-touch-move-action-move

Comment: sure, I tried this:
 int fromLoc[] = new int[2];

   holes[6].getLocationOnScreen(fromLoc);     
   float startX = fromLoc[0];


   float startY = fromLoc[1];

Comment: Formatting for legibility

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getX() and getY() methods? They return an int representing view position in pixels.

Comment: Be aware of the actual pixel coordinates of the screen though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483345/how-do-android-screen-coordinates-work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a game with smooth animation,I advice to use a fullscreen SurfaceView or View and draw the ball and hole with canvas. It is not suitable to make a game by using android Widget such as ImageView.