# Mapping cartesian coordinates on android screen

Tags: android, coordinates, tracking, ibeacon

I am working on a project where I get distances from individual beacons placed in a room and I need to convert those distances into Cartesian Coordinates.
Using the Trilateral method, I obtained the coordinates as X and Y but now the real question is How to show/represent/map these (X,Y) points on my Android screen as a Floating Action Button?
Can I use Margins and Density pixel for this purpose? If so, then how?

Comment: Aaaaand why exactly you want to use a Floating Action Button for that?

Comment: Follow the [how-do-android-screen-coordinates-work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483345/how-do-android-screen-coordinates-work)

Comment: @BartoszLipinski I am implementing Indoor location tracking and "I think" by using floating action button on a relative layout, I can get my location by using a layout inflater and could also provide actions when I tap on the button.

Comment: I used a canvas and used a bitmap that moves around. So far so good but Now I have a problem of scaling that canvas.