# Draw text below Circle

Tags: android, canvas, text, view, geometry

I want to draw text below circle in canvas. Following is my code but text is drawn above circle.

```
 canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, radius, paint);
 canvas.drawText(text, 0, (radius*2), textPaint);
```

Comment: Try negating the height value `-(radius*2)`

Comment: see `Canvas#drawText` documentation

Comment: @Doomsknight negative not working

Comment: did you read `Canvas#drawText` documentation?

Comment: Document confusing me.It says"Draw the text, with origin at (x,y), using the specified paint. The origin is interpreted based on the Align setting in the paint." I set alignment left.

Comment: Looking at it properly you need to set the y value based on height of the canvas, same way you did the circle, then adjust it to be Below based on radius. `(getHeight() / 2) + radius`. One thing that may be confusing you is that the origion is the top left. And that increase in Y is downwards

Comment: (getHeight() / 2) + radius worked. Thank you.

Comment: Thought it would, glad to know. Posted it as an answer too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at it properly you need to set the y value based on height of the canvas, same way you did the circle, then adjust it to be Below based on radius.

```
canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, radius, paint);
canvas.drawText(text, 0, (getHeight() / 2) + radius, textPaint);
```

One thing that may be confusing you is that the origion is the top left. And that increase in Y is downwards

You may need to add a few extra pixels based on text height. so `(getHeight() / 2) + radius + 20`

Comment: See this regarding screen/canvas coordinates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483345/how-do-android-screen-coordinates-work