# get ImageView gravity progmatically

Tags: android, layout, imageview, android-relativelayout, toolbar

Hey I have an imageView in a toolbar layout and its gravity is set to "start" , but I need to know where is start so I can know in which direction the arrow sould turn.
How can I get the "start" of the screen pragmatically?

Comment: Please explain clearly..

Comment: Please explain clearly with example or image.

Comment: You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483345/how-do-android-screen-coordinates-work) it explain how coordinates loooks like and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619693/getting-views-coordinates-relative-to-the-root-layout) how to get relative position to parent.