# Android - Is it possible to make a navigation on a .png?

Tags: java, android, navigation, blender, esri

I get a lat long from the backend and I want to use a PNG as a map, because this map is self made. So I want to transfer my lat long on this PNG and then draw at this position a point, but I couldn't figure it out how to do... 
I couldn't find it here in another question. Maybe it's so easy that no one ever asked this.

I am new to Android and new to stackoverflow :)

EDIT because of comment: The image is a self made map. It was made with ESRI cityengine and Blender. Then I made a birdseye-screenshot of the map and this screenshot I want to use as my map.

EDIT 2: @MarkusKauppinen made a good comment! So I also want to convert the lat/long to x/y coordinates of the screen (like ([How do android screen coordinates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483345/how-do-android-screen-coordinates-work)) ). But the lat/long of my backend don't relate to the lat/long of the Earth.

Comment: It's not very clear from your question what you want. Do you want an image of Google Map with your lat,lng on it? Then you can try https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro

Comment: The image is a self made map. It was made with ESRI cityengine and Blender. Then I made a birdseye-screenshot of the map and this screenshot I want to use as my map.

Comment: Use a Custom TileProvider in Google Maps for Android: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14784841/295004 and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay

Comment: Of course you can draw points on that map yourself. Has little to do with Android. Just calculate some x,y values. Thats all.

Comment: Is the problem [converting lat/lon to x/y coordinates?](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51833.html) The link explains the necessary math. (Probably accurate enough for this purpose.)

Comment: All thx for your comments! Appreciate it alot!
@MorrisonChang Could you tell me if this Tileprovider works without integrating the map of googlemaps?

Comment: @greenapps would you do it with a Canvas?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Thanks I edited my question because of your comment. See EDIT 2. So I want to convert the lat/long to x/y coordinates of the screen (like [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483345/how-do-android-screen-coordinates-work) ). But the lat/long of my backend don't relate to the lat/long of the Earth.

Comment: Your map has a resolution in pixels. WxH. You should first, given a lat,lon, calculate an x,y in pixels for your map. If you are ready with that then you can try to display the map and convert map x,y to screen x,y.

Comment: @greenapps thx i will try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even thought that this question has a downvote and probably no one will ever see it, I could figure it out how to solve my problem.
I used this [Canvas Bitmap Method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) to draw the map on my screen. Then I converted the lat/long coordinates so that they fit on the Screen of the mobile phone with the help of this post: [How do android screen coordinates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483345/how-do-android-screen-coordinates-work)
With the converted lat/long coordinates then I could [draw a circle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle(float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) on the current position on the map. Now when the coordinates change the circle is moving like it should.