# How to get XYPlot axis with OnTouchListener

Tags: android, androidplot

I'm trying to get the axis of an XYPlot using a custom OnTouchListener:

```
mPlot.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                float touchX = event.getX();
                float touchY = event.getY();
                Log.d(TAG, touchX+":"+touchY);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The problem is that I'm getting the pixel values.

Is there any method or workaround to get the exact axis of the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked some [androidplot doc](https://149-1424783-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/tmp/circle-artifacts.s0GaIso/javadoc/index.html) and apaprently `XYPlot` object has these methods, maybe they're what you need

```
public Number screenToSeriesX(float x)

public Number screenToSeriesY(float y)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works but these methods are deprecated for newer versions where we should use screenToSeriesX() and screenToSeriesY().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int touchX = (int) event.getX();
int touchY = (int) event.getY();
```

For more info on how Android Screen Coordinates work : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11483404/6544105)