# Placing confetti to fall from top instead of top left only

Tags: java, android

I recently came across this library.

https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Konfetti

I tried to implement it in my application. I read the documentation and tried to implement it. Below is my code:

JAVA FILE:

```
final KonfettiView konfettiView = findViewById(R.id.viewConfetti);
konfettiView.build()
                .addColors(Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA)
                .setDirection(0.0, 359.0)
                .setSpeed(1f, 5f)
                .setFadeOutEnabled(true)
                .setTimeToLive(2000L)
                .addShapes(Shape.Square.INSTANCE, Shape.Circle.INSTANCE)
                .addSizes(new Size(12, 5))
                .setPosition(-50f, konfettiView.getWidth() + 50f, -50f, -50f)
                .streamFor(300, 1500L);
```

Below is my Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/folk"
    tools:context=".TrueActivity">

<nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.KonfettiView
        android:id="@+id/viewConfetti"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CongoText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/congratulations"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textColor= "#FFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Everything is working fine for me. But the confetti is ejected from the top left only. I tried to change the `KonfettiView` object to different dimensions (i.e. trying to change the `X-axis`); but to no avail. I even read below answer on Stack overflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46016959/13627957

But it doesn't seem to help. **Is there any way I could get it ejected from full top as shown in the main library  [`readme file`](https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Konfetti#demo-app) instead of only top left.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**DisplayMetrics**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics) class' constant `widthPixels` instead of `konfettiView.getWidth()` method to achieve your results.

> Speaking about the two; your `konfettiView.getWidth()` uses the Konfetti width whereas `DisplayMetrics.widthPixels` uses device width. Information about [**width pixels.**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics#widthPixels)

Try the code below:

```
DisplayMetrics display = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(display);
final KonfettiView konfettiView = findViewById(R.id.viewConfetti);
konfettiView.build()
                .addColors(Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA)
                .setDirection(0.0, 359.0)
                .setSpeed(1f, 5f)
                .setFadeOutEnabled(true)
                .setTimeToLive(2000L)
                .addShapes(Shape.Square.INSTANCE, Shape.Circle.INSTANCE)
                .addSizes(new Size(12, 5))
                .setPosition(-50f, display.widthPixels + 50f, -50f, -50f)
                .streamFor(300, 1500L);
```