# Is the WindowManager.LayoutParams x/y position 1-based or 0-based?

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, layoutparams

Are the [x](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#x)/[y](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#y) positions of a window declared as 1-based? (in other words inclusive of the first pixel of the window), so that with `x=1` and `y =1` the window would fit in the left top corner without having a 1px gap before its left and top edges?

If that's the case would setting x/y to 0/0 be valid and allowed? Would that cause the window to hang out of the screen area by 1px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left top corner corresponds to **0/0** as **x/y**

**UPDATE**:
Refer to this question on stackoverflow [How do android screen coordinates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483345/how-do-android-screen-coordinates-work)