# How to set the size of the layer as a percentage?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I use dip now. But on devices with mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi...  proportions are different.
For example:
[image]

I know that on mdpi 1px = 1dp. 
hdpi 1.00dp = 1.50px
xhdpi 1.00dp = 2.00px

Resolutin on hdpi 480x800, on xhdi usualy 720x1280 ... DP is useless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `android:layout_weight="25"` for the 25% item and continue so on and so forth until you have done all the items in your `LinearLayout`.

So for instance:

```
android:layout_weight="25"
android:layout_weight="15"
android:layout_weight="50"
android:layout_weight="35"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't mention Percentage for dimension.

Instead you can use `android:layout_weight` attribute inside LinearLayout.

Read more: [What does android:layout_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'android:layout_weight' param of `LinearLayout` children:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <View 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="25" />
    <View 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="15" />
    <View 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50" />
    <View 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="35" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can not do it from XML, byt u can always set  width,height by calculation(depending on total size of screen, and setting your views param accordingly) in Java code, like in this link

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11256947/519718)