# Android, add view with height in percentage

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-view, android-relativelayout

i wanna add a view with a 100% width and X%(e.g: lets make it 40%) to the parent view

i have this:

```
private RelativeLayout getParentView(){
    return (RelativeLayout) MyActivity.this.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
}
```

i should cast parent view to LinearLayout or RelativeLayout can achieve this ?

and how to set 'myView' width and height in percentage programmatically ?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK you can only do that with linearlayouts and weight. Set weight-sum to 1 and set the child view's height/width to 0.x percent

Comment: i dont wanna do this in XML just programmatically,

Comment: what first, i should add a Linear Layout to parent view ? and then add myView to the LinearLayout ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this by simply getting the screen width

```
  public static int getScreenWidth(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    return displayMetrics.widthPixels;
}
```

Multiply that by the percentage and give the parameters to view like this:

```
//For 40% height according to the screen width.
view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (getScreenWidth(mContext) * 0.40);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: u wanna say getScreen*Height* ?

Comment: You can calculate by both ways. Say i want to divide my screen into 2 equal parts then i will work with return displayMetrics.heightPixels and give the height * 0.5. The above code is for maintaining the aspect ratio of a view when different width devices comes across and you want to have a view with same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void updateDimen(Activity activity){
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
}
```

Use above code to get screen height and screen width.

Then get the instance of your Layout, get its LayoutParams instance and update the dimension

```
params.height = screenHeight * 0.6;
params.width = screenWidth * 0.6;
```